# How to use for loop inside svg to draw lines

Tags: javascript, svg

I want to draw lines inside of svg using javascript. I have polygon and I want to draw line inside using for loop that will finish when its get full in that shape. I've try but the line can't appear when I render it.

Here's my code:

```
<div id="svgselect" style="width: 610px; height: 230px;">
      <!-- background-color:red -->
      <svg version="1.1" height="100%" width="100%">
        <g transform="scale(1.5)" id="gmain">

          <g id="P17" transform="translate(25,0)">
            <polygon class="line" points="5,5  15,5  15,15   5,15" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="C" opacity="1"></polygon>
            <polygon class="line" points="0,0  20,0  15,5  5,5" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="T" opacity="1"></polygon>
            <polygon class="line" points="5,15   15,15   20,20   0,20" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="B" opacity="1" class="B17"></polygon>
            <polygon class="line" points="15,5   20,0  20,20   15,15" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="R" opacity="1"></polygon>
            <polygon class="line" points="0,0  5,5   5,15  0,20" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="L" opacity="1"></polygon>
            <text x="6" y="30" stroke="navy" fill="navy" stroke-width="0.1" style="font-size: 6pt;font-weight:normal">17</text>
          </g>
          <g id="P16" transform="translate(50,0)">
            <polygon class="line" points="5,5  15,5  15,15   5,15" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="C" opacity="1"></polygon>
            <polygon class="line" points="0,0  20,0  15,5  5,5" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="T" opacity="1"></polygon>
            <polygon class="line" points="5,15   15,15   20,20   0,20" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="B" opacity="1" class="B16"></polygon>
            <polygon class="line" points="15,5   20,0  20,20   15,15" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="R" opacity="1"></polygon>
            <polygon class="line" points="0,0  5,5   5,15  0,20" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="L" opacity="1"></polygon>
            <text x="6" y="30" stroke="navy" fill="navy" stroke-width="0.1" style="font-size: 6pt;font-weight:normal">16</text>
          </g>
          <g id="P15" transform="translate(75,0)">
            <polygon class="line" points="5,5  15,5  15,15   5,15" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="C" opacity="1"></polygon>
            <polygon class="line" points="0,0  20,0  15,5  5,5" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="T" opacity="1"></polygon>
            <polygon class="line" points="5,15   15,15   20,20   0,20" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="B" opacity="1" class="B15"></polygon>
            <polygon class="line" points="15,5   20,0  20,20   15,15" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="R" opacity="1"></polygon>
            <polygon class="line" points="0,0  5,5   5,15  0,20" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="L" opacity="1"></polygon>
            <text x="6" y="30" stroke="navy" fill="navy" stroke-width="0.1" style="font-size: 6pt;font-weight:normal">15</text>

          </g>
        </g>
      </svg>

  </div>
```

script :

```
var group = evt.target.parentNode;
              // Get the bounding box of the group
              var bbox = group.getBBox();
              // Add a triangle to the group
              var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
              var shape = document.createElementNS(svgns, "polygon");
              var line = document.createElementNS(svgns, "line")
              shape.setAttribute("points", "0,0, 0,20, 20,20, 20,0");
              shape.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "none");
              shape.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke", "black")
              shape.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-width", 2.5);
              line.setAttribute('id','line');
            line.setAttribute('x1','3');
            line.setAttribute('y1','0');
            line.setAttribute('x2','3');
            line.setAttribute('y2','20');
            line.setAttribute("stroke", "black");
            var xPos = bbox.x ;  
              var yPos = bbox.y ;    
              shape.setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + xPos + "," + yPos + ")");
              line.setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + xPos + "," + yPos + ")");
              group.appendChild(shape);
            for (a=0; a >= 20 ; a+3){
                group.appendChild(line);
            }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nanadia/rq3L1axv/4/

Big Thanks

Comment: You've only one line, appending it 20 times will result in 1 line being appended because appendChild replaces the child if it's already in the DOM.

Comment: @RobertLongson so what should I use?

Comment: you need to do the line creation (the document.createElementNS) in the loop

Comment: @RobertLongson the lines still don't appear

Comment: I don't see your updated code in the question so I can't see what else you're doing wrong

Comment: @RobertLongson you can check now https://jsfiddle.net/nanadia/rq3L1axv/10/

Comment: That's going to draw all the lines on top of each other isn't it, and it's going to give them all invalid duplicate id values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164444/discussion-between-kitcat-and-robert-longson).